# How to get values from one model to appear in another in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django so please be kind -_^.

I have two models "cats" and "litters".

Litters contain two elements with names.

I have a bunch of Cats.

I want it so as a user, I can associate any cat with a litter according to the litter names existing in the litter model.

How do I make that happen?

(I have attempted "one-to-many", "many-to-many" and "reverse relations"...I am NEW to DJANGO so I don't claim that any of those attempts where done correctly.

Here is my current models.py

```
...
class Litter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True, null=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save time Litter object modified and created times
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.created:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

        super(Litter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cat(models.Model):
    litter_mates = models.ManyToManyField(Litter)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female')
    )
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'

    CAT_TYPE = (
        ('O','Orphan'),
        ('P','Pregnant'),
        ('N','Nursing')
    )
    Orphan = 'O'
    Pregnant = 'P'
    Nursing = 'N'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    reference_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    short_name = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
                                  help_text="This name is auto generated from the name and reference ID. "
                                            "It is used to make it easy to find the animal in a URL lookup.")

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=MALE)
    cat_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CAT_TYPE, default=Orphan)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    weight_unit = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Weight.MEASURE_CHOICES, default=Weight.GRAMS)
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to="kitty_photos", blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    alert_feeder = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                       help_text='Alert feeder to critical situations')
    critical_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    first_weight_loss = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    second_weight_loss = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    third_weight_loss = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    many_weight_losses = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Check to see if slug exists, if it does, make a counter
        self.slug = orig = slugify(self.name)

        for x in itertools.count(1):
            if not Cat.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists():
                break
            self.slug = '%s-%d' % (orig, x)

        self.modified = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.created:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.short_name = slugify("{name}-{reference_id}".format(name=self.name, reference_id=self.reference_id))

        super(Cat, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'tracker:cat', (self.slug,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

...
```

and here is my serializers.py

```
...
class LitterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Litter
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'notes'
        )


class CatSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    litter_mates = LitterSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'reference_id',
            'short_name',
            'gender',
            'cat_type',
            'litter_mates',
            'color',
            'weight_unit',
            'weight',
            'notes',
            'birthday',
            'photo',
            'created',
            'modified',
            'alert_feeder',
            'critical_notes',
            'first_weight_loss',
            'second_weight_loss',
            'third_weight_loss',
            'many_weight_losses'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        litter_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        cat = Cat.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for litter_data in litter_data:
            Litter.objects.create(cat=cat, **litter_data)
        return cat


...
```

Now I figure if I can get my admin page at http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cats/  to show me a create / update a cat form containing a "litter_mates" drop-down containing the names of my two litters...I'll have what I need.

thank you for looking.

UPDATED:

here is also my **admin.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib import admin
from jsoneditor.forms import JSONEditor
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from . import models as tracker_models
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources


class LitterResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = tracker_models.Litter


class MedicationResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = tracker_models.Medication


class FeedingResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = tracker_models.Feeding


class CatResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = tracker_models.Cat


class LitterAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name', 'created', 'modified']
    resource_class = LitterResource


class MedicationAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['cat__name', 'notes']
    list_display = ['cat', 'duration', 'notes', 'frequency', 'dosage', 'dosage_unit',
                    'created', 'modified']
    resource_class = MedicationResource


class FeedingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = tracker_models.Feeding
    extra = 1
    exclude = ['modified']
    readonly_fields = ['created']


class FeedingAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['cat__name', 'amount_of_food_taken', 'notes']
    list_display = ['cat', 'weight_unit_measure', 'weight_before_food', 'food_unit_measure', 'amount_of_food_taken',
                    'food_type', 'weight_after_food', 'stimulated', 'stimulation_type', 'notes', 'photo',
                    'created', 'modified']
    resource_class = FeedingResource


class CatAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'reference_id', 'short_name', 'gender', 'notes']
    list_display = ['name', 'reference_id', 'short_name', 'gender', 'weight_unit', 'weight', 'notes', 'birthday', 'photo',
                    'alert_feeder', 'critical_notes', 'first_weight_loss', 'second_weight_loss', 'third_weight_loss',
                    'many_weight_losses', 'created', 'modified']
    inlines = [
        FeedingInline
    ]
    resource_class = CatResource


__custom_admins__ = {
    'Cat': CatAdmin,
    'Feeding': FeedingAdmin,
    'Medication': MedicationAdmin,
    'Litter': LitterAdmin,
}

for model in tracker_models.__admin__:
    params = [getattr(tracker_models, model)]
    if model in __custom_admins__:
        params.append(__custom_admins__[model])
    else:
        _dyn_class = type('%sAdmin' % ( model,), (admin.ModelAdmin,), {})
        params.append(_dyn_class)
    admin.site.register(*params)

admin.site.site_title = 'KittyTracker Admin'
admin.site.site_header = 'KittyTracker Admin'
```

UPDATE TWO:

now when I go to "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cats/" I get the following error...

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column tracker_cat.litter_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "tracker_cat"."id", "tracker_cat"."litter_id", "track...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a many to one relation in your Cats model.
This will allow you to assign you cat to a litter, a litter which can contain many cats.

```
class Cat(models.Model):
...
litter = models.ForeignKey(Litter, on_delete=None)
...
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include my intire admin.py....I'm not clear on where exactly to register my 2 classes in that file (I'm new to Django)

Comment: Just add the 2 lines to the very bottom and you should be ready to go.

Comment: when I add those two lines to the very bottom of my admin.py I get an error that says "Unrsolved reference ..."

Comment: You'll have to import your models as well. Like this: `from .models import Cat, Litter`

Comment: "django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Cat is already registered"

Comment: Please LOOK at admin.py above please

Comment: I didn't see your customization. So you already had your classes registered, so need to register them again. If you simply add `'litter'` to your `CatAdmin` class, does that not do what you want to do? Send me a message if not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173696/discussion-between-jessi-and-philip-blonde).